# Как пройтись по всем страницам сайта и посмотреть сколько товаров на макс странице

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
"""
```

Как пройтись по всем страницам сайта и посмотреть сколько товаров на макс странице. Я не могу проитись по страницам, если даже ставлю в код страница 10 он мне выдает только 1 страницу и 24 товара!
    Не могу зайти на все страницы, там только загрузить еще вместо номеров страниц
    """

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
import csv

headers = {'accept': '*/*',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/78.0.3904.108 Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
base_url = 'https://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/cat/krovati-bm003/page-2/'
second_url = 'https://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/'

def ikea_parser(base_url, headers):
    urls = []
    urls.append(base_url)
    page_ikea = []
    page_ikea.append('https://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/')
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers=headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        request = session.get(base_url, headers=headers)
        soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')
        try:
            for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'pagination'}):
                print(item)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        print('ERROR')
ikea_parser(base_url, headers)
```

Comment: *>>на макс странице* - что такое макс страница?

Comment: на максимальной странице скажем 10 страница, зайти и посмотреть каталог товаров. Там должно быть не меньше 200 товаров так как в одной странице там 24 товара. Я там брал 2 страницу но у меня также 24 товара а должно быть 48. Скорее я не там что то делаю )